# C++ function to add space between digits and alpahbets

Tags: c++

I have this string which look like this

```
90hello
```

I wanted to add a space between them, so I created a function

```cpp
    int size = text.length();
    int flag = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        flag=0
        if(isdigit(text[i]) && isalpha(text[i+1])){
            for (int j=size+!; j<0; j--) {
                text[j] == text[j-1];
            }
            flag++;
        }
        if(flag!=0)
            text[i+1]=" ";
    }
```

but this would only do `90 llo`

what did I miss??

**edit:**
I typed it again so I could help others to read my problematic code easier, but I guess I didn't do the good job. Sorry guys.

Alright, This is the code in my program if it's better!

```cpp
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    string s, gendata;


    while (getline(cin,s)){
        gendata += s;
    }


    int size = gendata.length();
    int flag=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < gendata.length(); i++){
        flag=0;
        if(isdigit(gendata[i]) && isalpha(gendata[i+1])){
            flag++;
            for (int j=size+1; j<0; j--) {
                gendata[j] = gendata[j-1];
            }
        }
        if(flag!=0)
            gendata[i+1] = ' ';
    }

    cout << gendata << endl;

}
```

it compiles but only does not give what I want.

Comment: Unfortunately, nobody will be able to help you because the shown code fails to meet the requirements of a [mre], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. It's obviously not the real code you compiled, because of an obvious typo that would prevent it from getting compiled, either. So, who knows what is the real problem with the real code, instead of the different code that was manually typed in your question. Please see [ask] on stackoverflow.com, and take a [tour], before [edit]ing your question, and fixing it based on the tips from the [help].

Comment: The entire innermost `for` loop looks flawed, but as Sam Varshavchik said, it's impossible to know which flaws exist in your real code and which were introduced as typos when you did not copy-and-paste your code (from something that had successfully compiled).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Hey thank you for letting me know the guide. I'll have a look before post another question. I added my actual code if it's better to look at. Thanks.

Comment: @JaMiT I added a code that compiles, if you like to have a look at it. Thanks for the comments anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in the code ... so first of all the loop

```
  for (int j = size + 1; j < 0; j--)
```

will always exit immediately .. j < 0 is never true. Changing that to

```
for (int j = size + 1; j > 0; j--)
```

.. is not really an improvement. It will cause an exception accessing an `gendata[size + j]` element which is behind the allowed range in the string. The string does NOT allocate implicitly memory in such cases. So the string must be extended .. and the size changes here (variable `size` must be increased) ... and some more.

Much easier than changing the source string in the loop is to write the result into a second `target` string:

```
  string target;
  for (int i = 0; i < (int) gendata.length(); i++) 
  {
    target += gendata[i];
    // check i for (i < gendata.length() - 1) !!!
    if (i < gendata.length() - 1 && isdigit(gendata[i]) && isalpha(gendata[i + 1]))
    {
      target += ' ';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in the code. The biggest one is that in order to make your string longer, someone must allocate more memory for it; you cannot simply overwrite the end of the current string. Often the allocation happens automatically for you, but only when you use a method that supports changing the length of the string (e.g. concatenation, as in `gendata += s`).

---

Let's go through some problematic lines.

```
int size = gendata.length();
```

You calculate the size of the string outside the loop, then use it inside the loop. However, if there is more than one digit-to-alpha transition, the size is (intended to be) outdated. You should use the current length of the string instead of this stale number.

```
int flag=0;
```

You are using `flag` as a yes/no toggle. The proper type for that (to express your intent) is `bool`. Also, this flag is used only inside the loop and it is reset to a false value with each iteration. Your code would be more organized if `flag` was declared inside the loop instead of outside it. (No errors from this at the moment, just style improvements.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < gendata.length(); i++){
```

Since you use `gendata[i+1]` inside the loop, you need to also make sure that `i+1 < gendata.length()`. Well, since `i+1 < gendata.length()` implies `i < gendata.length()`, most people would check just the former instead of checking both.

Also, if you turn on your compiler's warnings, you should get a warning about comparing signed and unsigned values (`i` is signed, while `string::length()` returns an unsigned value). It's a pain at first, but appeasing those warnings tends to be beneficial in the long run.

```
        for (int j=size+1; j<0; j--) {
```

This is the line that had a typo initially. Apparently the `<` is actually in your code. You probably meant `>`, since you appear to be trying to loop from a positive number down to zero. (Plus, as I mentioned earlier, you should use `gendata.length()` instead of `size` here since your intent is to have possibly changed the length of the string.)

```
            gendata[j] = gendata[j-1];
```

When `j` is `size+1`, the expression `gendata[j]` results in undefined behavior. When `j` is `size`, assigning a (non-null) value to `gendata[j]` results in undefined behavior. See [`string::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at).

---

OK, time to look for a solution. You are making things hard on yourself by trying to manipulate a string's data instead of manipulating the string itself. You could simply [tell the string to insert a space](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert): `gendata.insert(i+1, 1, ' ');`. The `i+1` is where you want the space to appear, the second parameter is the number of spaces to insert, and the `' '` is the character to insert.

By using the string's API, your outer `for` loop can become much shorter.

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i+1 < gendata.length(); i++){
    if(isdigit(gendata[i]) && isalpha(gendata[i+1])){
        gendata.insert(i+1, 1, ' ');
    }
}
```

There is a caveat with this sort of code though: you are changing the string that you are iterating over. When this happens, extra care is warranted to make sure the change doesn't disrupt the loop. (In this case, it works since a space is not a digit.)